# How to reset the rdtsc when using in an assembly file. I need to read in the before and after clock cycle data

Tags: assembly, rdtsc

Does the rdtsc stop when it is used in the assembly file? Is there a flagged raised? And how do i reset it? I have read the first clock stamp into the rdx register. But when I try to print the clock cycle again after waiting for a few seconds it is still the same number.

Comment: It never stops.  Use EAX instead.

Comment: Be careful: CPU has one TSC register per each CPU core, they may contain different values.

Comment: How precisely do you use RDTSC? Why are you reading only EDX (the high 32 bits of the time stamp)? Assuming a clock on the order of GHz, EDX will only change every couple seconds. You need to read both EDX and EAX (the low 32 bits), and combine them into a 64-bit value. Each core has its own RDTSC counter; you must insure that your app doesn't hop to another core. And although you may reset the value returned by RDTSC if this is kernel-mode code with a WRMSR instruction targeting MSR 0x10 (IA32_TIME_STAMP_COUNTER), you should *not* do so, as many things may depend on it strictly incrementing.

Comment: If you're curious about my comment above, the Intel Software Developers' Manual, Volume 3, Chapter 17, Section 17.13.3 `Time-Stamp Counter Adjustment` states _Software can modify the value of the time-stamp counter (TSC) of a logical processor by using the WRMSR instruction to write to the IA32_TIME_STAMP_COUNTER MSR (address 10H). Because such a write applies only to that logical processor, [each core must write to its own TSC to synchronize]. It may be difficult for software to do this in a way than ensures that all [cores] will have the same value for the TSC at a given point in time._

Answer (score 1):

As Hans hints at, `rdtsc` returns the current cycle counter as a 64-bit value in the 32-bit register pair `edx:eax` with the most significant part in `edx`.

To my knowledge, there is no way to reset this counter other than by restarting the computer.